# Derivatives relation

Tags: functions, derivatives

Please, help me solve the following problem:

> Suppose $$\frac{df(x,y)}{dx}>0, \qquad \frac{df(x,y)}{dy}<0, \qquad  \frac{d^2f(x,y)}{dxdy}<0$$ Is it true that if $y_{2}>y_{1}>0$ then $\dfrac{df(x,y_{1})}{dx}>\dfrac{df(x,y_{2})}{dx}$?

Will be very grateful for help!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the statement is true as it possible to write $\frac{d^2f(x,y)}{dxdy}=\frac{d(\frac{df(x,y)}{dx})}{dy}<0$ so derivative $\frac{df(x,y)}{d(x)}$ stricktly decrease while $y$ goes up.